# My erode() function doesn't produce same output as openCV's erode function

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

So i've used a border for the pixels that are 'outside' the image so the kernel can use the border's pixels to get a minimum. 
I've no idea why my function would produce a different output to that of the inbuilt function - I've inspected both outputs carefully (writing to an image and zooming in) and looking very carefully I can't notice a difference in pixels!

import cv2
    import numpy as np

```
img = cv2.imread('lena.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

reflect = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,3,3,3,3,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)

cv2.imshow('img', reflect)
cv2.waitKey(0)

imgEroded = np.zeros((512+6,512+6,3), np.uint8)

for i in range(0,reflect.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,reflect.shape[1]):
        n = np.matrix(reflect[i-3:i+2, j-3:j+2])
        if n.size > 0:  
            imgEroded[i][j] = n.min()

imgEroded = imgEroded[3:512+3, 3:512+3]

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erode = cv2.erode(img,kernel)
# print  erode.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow('erosionCorrect',erode)
cv2.imshow('erosion',imgEroded)

cv2.imwrite('myOutput.png',imgEroded)
cv2.imwrite('correct.png',erode)


print(np.array_equal(erode, imgEroded))

# cv2.imshow('real',erode)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine except two small issues:

First, `imgEroded` is a three-channel image while `erode` is a single channel image (you read `img` as grayscale), so just simply create a single-channel `imgEroded`.

Second, you're one pixel off in your indexing for your `n` matrix. If you index an array like `arr[i-3:i+2]` this means starting at index `i-3` and going *up to* `i+2`, which means you're indexing `i-3, i-2, i-1, i, i+1`. This has size five, which is correct, but the center isn't `i`, it's `i-1`. So you should be indexing `i-2:i+3`. Same with `j` of course. This also means you actually only need to `copyMakeBorder()` two pixels wide and not three, but that's not really a big deal.

With these two changes:

```
imgEroded = np.zeros((512+6,512+6), np.uint8)
```

and

```
n = np.matrix(reflect[i-2:i+3, j-2:j+3])
```

on the corresponding lines, `print(np.array_equal(erode, imgEroded))` prints `True`.

FYI to help debug images that *look* similar, I find *printing the numpy image array* to be super helpful; that's how I spotted both errors. The 1-ch vs 3-ch is immediately obvious, but then after correcting that I simply noticed that the second matrix was basically the same but shifted a pixel in each direction.